# How to clone a specific branch in git bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-svn

I want to clone a specific branch. I don't want download the `master` branch.

How do I clone the whole project and then switch to `validations` branch?

Answer (score 47):

You can clone a single branch (without inadvertently cloning the whole project) with the following:

```
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch [<folder>]
```

Alternatively (attempting to address your new question here...), you can clone the whole project

```
git clone <url>
```

Change directories into the folder and creating a new branch off of master with

```
git checkout -b validations
```

Comment: this is my project and I have a branch called validations

Comment: How I clone the whole project and then I after change the branch master to brach validations

Comment: that sounds like a different question...it sounds like you are now wondering how to clone a git project and then create a branch off of master...?

Comment: I want to use the brach validations, but  to use validations not master

Answer (score 45):

```
git clone -b branchName remote_repo_url
```

For example `git clone -b develop https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView.git`

Answer (score 12):

To pull a separate branch, you need to follow two simple steps.

**1. Create a new branch**

**2. Pull the required branch**

Try using the following commands:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
git pull origin <branch-to-pull>
```

You will now have all the contents in the `<new-branch-name>` branch

Comment: I need to clone this branch  https://bitbucket.org/juanperez/alhambra/branch/validations

Answer (score 9):

Use git clone as following :

```
git clone -b specific/Branch --single-branch git://sub.domain.com/repo.git
```

And, Helpful link is

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone/1.7.10

Also, If you get an error with "--single-branch", then removed it -b will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

once you're done adding your ssh key, you can follow up with: `git clone -b <branch_name> <url_to_repository>`

replace all angular brackets with your required branch name and repository URL.

Answer (score 1):

Using below command not only you can clone specific branch from origin but also create and checkout locally at same time

To see remote branches do

```
git branch -r
```

Then

```
git checkout -b <local branch name> origin/<branch name>
example: git checkout -b Bug_1 origin/Develop
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Sourcetree? If so, select three dots and choose "Checkout in Sourcetree" And then Clone it.